# How to indent text in a textview in android?

Tags: android, textview

Im trying to make the text much easier to read by making seperate paragraphs. I've tried adding spaces before the text in the string resource but it doesn't work. Im wondering if it's possible to add attribute to textview, or in the string resource itself.

Thanks Rob

Comment: Could you add some code or give some more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use \t for tab \n for newline.it works for sure.
and write this attribute to your textview in your xml

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

For  more attributes of Textview take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)