# Android - indent text on a textview

Tags: android, text, textview, indentation

I know that this may be quite simple but i cannot seem to find out how to indent some text inside of a text view. I've already tried using google however the results shown don't seem to be much help.

Does anyone here have any ideas?

Comment: please post your code and clarify what you want exactly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190477/how-to-indent-text-in-a-textview-in-android

Comment: Add some padding to your TextView

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What do you mean by Indent what I understand

You can achieve it two ways

1. Setting Padding
2. Setting Margin

For **Padding & Margin** it will look like this

### First one is due to Padding

### Second one is due to Margin

I think now you will deeply understand concept of margin and padding

[image: Padding & Margin]

## Code Samples

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewYouTube"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Not LoggedIn"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Yes the padding was exactually what i was after. Thanks for your input!