# Tab Character is shown as single space on a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to show some text that uses the TAB character to ident, but it is shown as a single space.

This is my code:

```
String text = "some\ttext"
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setText(text);
```

And this is the output:

> "some text"

When It should be something like this:

```
 "some   text"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to indent text in a textview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190477/how-to-indent-text-in-a-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

On my phone

```
tv.setText("Some\ttext");
```

places a tab, while

```
tv.setText("some\ttext");
```

doesn't. On another device both don't work.

I guess you're better off using multiple spaces instead of tabs here.